# How do I get 2 values from useParams()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the values `:URL_name` and `:teamName` from using params to display the teams information

```
 <Route path="/:URL_name/equipos/:teamName" element={<TeamInfoPage />} />
```

I can manage to get it to display `:URL_name` but I get this error trying to display `:teamName`

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

and this is the `<Link>` tag that is sending me there

```
      <Link
        to={`/${tournament.URL_name}/equipos/${team.name}`}
        className="teamCard"
      >
        <div className="teamName">{text}</div>
      </Link>
```

and this is supposed to be the TeamInfoPage

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

// Data
import { tournaments_data } from "../__FakeDatabase/Tournaments_data";

function TeamInfoPage() {
  const { URL_name, teamName } = useParams();
  const tournament = tournaments_data.find((p) => p.URL_name === URL_name);
  const team = tournaments_data.find((p) => p.teamName === teamName);

  return (
    <div className="teamInfoPage">
      <h1>Team Info</h1>
      {tournament.name}
      {team.name}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TeamInfoPage;
```

and then this is the data im trying to get

```
export const tournaments_data = [
  {
    name: "Futbol Rapido Varonil 2023",
    URL_name: "futbol-rapido-varonil",
    hostName: "Municipio de Galeana",
    thumbnail:
      "https://cdn.resfu.com/media/img_news/agencia-efe_multimedia_3273369.multimedia.photos.12911011.file.jpg?size=1200x&lossy=1",
    sex: "male",

    isCompleted: false,
    inBracketStages: true,
    bracketStage: "finals",

    bracketMatches: {
      quarterFinals: varonil_quartos,
      semiFinals: varonil_semis,
      finals: varonil_finales,
    },

    matchesSchedule: varonil_Schedule,
    teamStats: varonil_teamStats,
  },
```

```
export const varonil_teamStats = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "RSD",
    primaryColor: "#B51437",

    stats: {
      wins: 14,
      draws: 1,
      loses: 3,
      drawWins: 1,
      goalsFor: 100,
      goalsAgainst: 42,
      matchesPlayed: 18,
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: There's no `teamName` property in your `tournaments_data` data. Looks like you meant to check the `name` property. It should be `const team = tournaments_data.find((p) => p.name === teamName);`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding `tournament.teamStats.find` to the `team` variable instead of `tournaments_data.find`

```
  const tournament = tournaments_data.find((p) => p.URL_name === URL_name);
  const team = tournament.teamStats.find((team) => team.name === teamName);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nageennayak thanks I edited it, hopefully its easier to understand